# How can I use Url.Content inside of a @helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I'm making some @helper's inside of the App_Code folder.  The intent is to completely replace my old HtmlHelpers written in a *.cs file with a string builder and all the other fun stuff.

Anyway, in a couple of places, I'm using Url.Content in src attributes of `<img>` tags.  These used to work fine as HtmlHelpers.  Now, that I got my code inside *.cshtml file in App_Code folder, the site doesn't want to compile:

> CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist
>   in the current context

What's a good way to solve this?  I wouldn't want to have a relative path there instead of path mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass it as argument to the helper:

```
@helper Foo(UrlHelper url) {
    @url.Action("~/foo");
}
```

and then:

```
@Foo(Url)
```

Comment: Lol!  I just realized, that helper isn't used anymore.  That works, thanks!